# Understanding How to Submit a Parallel Computing Job on Slurm

Tags: parallel-processing, simulation, slurm

I am using a fluids solver called IAMR and I am trying to make it execute faster via my schools cluster. I have options to add nodes and specify tasks, but I have no clue what the distinction is our what my simulation needs to run. I am trying to render a single simulation and so far the following slurm script has worked:

=============================

```
#!/bin/bash  
#SBATCH --job-name=first_slurm_job   
#SBATCH -N 10  
#SBATCH -p debug_queue  
#SBATCH --time=4:00:00  # format days-hh:mm:ss  

./amr3d.gnu.MPI.OMP.ex inputs.3d.rt
```

==============================

Aside from not knowing how many nodes and tasks to request, I am not sure I am submitting the job correctly. In the IAMR guide it states:
For an MPI build, you can run in parallel using, e.g.:

mpiexec -n 4 ./amr2d.gnu.DEBUG.MPI.ex inputs.2d.bubble

But I am not using that line when I make the job submission. I asked a friend and they said: *typically "tasks" means "MPI processes", so if you break your problem into 4 grids then the way AMReX works, you can have each MPI rank update one grid , so with 4 grids you would ask for 4 MPI processes.* So does that mean I have to figure out how to make the grid split into 4 parts if I request 4 tasks? Any insight would help! Here are my clusters specs:

[Cluster Specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSLlI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yor file name us `amr3d.gnu.MPI.OMP.ex`. Is this a OpenMP program (parallel using multiple cores) or a MPI program (using multiple processes possible on multiple nodes) or a hybrid program using both like the filename sounds like?

Ok, it is a hybrid program, so we say you use 2 nodes with 16 cores each, then you can do it like

```
#!/bin/bash  
#SBATCH --job-name=first_slurm_job   
#SBATCH -p debug_queue  
#SBATCH --time=4:00:00  # format days-hh:mm:ss  

#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16
#SBATCH --ntasks=2
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=16

echo "Used nodes:" $SLURM_NODELIST
mpirun ./amr3d.gnu.MPI.OMP.ex inputs.3d.rt
```

Comment: I have been told it is hybrid and the user guide also agrees with this. I appreciate you explaining those two terms to me. "The name of the executable (generated by the make system) encodes several of the build characteristics, including dimensionality of the problem, compiler name, and whether MPI and/or OpenMP were linked with the executable."

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm!!! I really appreciate the help.